# Using the same dates for min/max and start/end for R shiny dateRangeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use `dateRangeInput` with the initial start and end dates being the same as the min and max dates, however this is causing problems. The code below is supposed to produce text to the right of the dateRangeInput box showing the number of days in the range and the start and end date, eg. "7 day period from 01/01/20 to 07/01/20"

Running this code results in the start date box being blank, and clicking on it shows the current month instead of January 2020. Plus the text does not get printed.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- (
  fluidPage(
    column(
      width = 6, 
      dateRangeInput(
        "dateRange",
        label = h4("Date range"),
        start = as.Date("2020-01-01"),
        end = as.Date("2020-01-30"),
        min = as.Date("2020-01-01"),
        max = as.Date("2020-01-30"),
        format = "dd/mm/yy",
        weekstart = 1
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      h4(textOutput("dateRangeText"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dateRangeText  <- renderText({
    dates <- input$dateRange
    dates_char <- format(dates, "%d/%m/%y")
    paste(as.numeric(dates[2] - dates[1]) + 1,
          "day period from", dates_char[1], "to", dates_char[2])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I change the ui to the following then it all works as expected, but with the downside that I now have an unwanted extra date at either end of the timeframe.

```
ui <- (
  fluidPage(
    column(
      width = 6, 
      dateRangeInput(
        "dateRange",
        label = h4("Date range"),
        start = as.Date("2020-01-01"),
        end = as.Date("2020-01-30"),
        min = as.Date("2020-01-01") - 1,
        max = as.Date("2020-01-30") + 1,
        format = "dd/mm/yy",
        weekstart = 1
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      h4(textOutput("dateRangeText"))
    )
  )
)
```

If I keep the original max date as `as.Date("2020-01-30")` but have the min date as `as.Date("2020-01-01") - 1` then the text to the right reads "NA day period from 01/01/20 to NA".

Comment: I tested your code and it is working. I believe you should update all `shiny` related packages!

Comment: @Duck I've now updated to shiny 1.5.0 but I'm still getting the same issue. The code itself runs without error but doesn't display the intended ```h4(textOutput("dateRangeText"))``` part

Comment: Do you mean the dynamic text that changes when you change the dates? I saw that when I tested your code!

Comment: @Duck yes that's right, my colleague had the same problem as me when he ran it on his machine, however we're both stuck at R 3.6.0 due to IT constraints so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: I also have R 3.6.0, it is weird maybe some IT locking issue! I would suggest open an account on RStudio Cloud and try running on it, if your IT permises allow you to open an account into this cloud!